# Java Event Binding Issue Binding Library

Tags: java, c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, java-binding

I transfered this https://github.com/blazsolar/HorizontalPicker Library into Java Binding Library.
The Library implements an OnItemSelected Event whicht is used like this in Java.

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(int index)    {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Item selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Now i want to use it like this in my C# Code.

```
var Picker = view.FindViewById<Com.Wefika.Horizontalpicker.HorizontalPicker>(Resource.Id.numberPicker);
Picker.onItemClicked+= delegate{};
```

Unfortunately onItemClicked does not exist.
I looked in the generated api xml and there it is declared.

```
<interface abstract="true" deprecated="not deprecated" final="false" name="HorizontalPicker.OnItemClicked" static="true" visibility="public">
<method abstract="true" deprecated="not deprecated" final="false" name="onItemClicked" native="false" return="void" static="false" synchronized="false" visibility="public">
```

Now I´m wondering how i can use this Event?
Do i have to modify something or can i get it on a different way?

Comment: Could you make the java binding library available, so i could check it out?

Comment: https://gitlab.com/Olias/binding/tree/master/Binding_HorizontalPicker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How it seems, the issue lies in the original project since it cant create a event delegate for it. You can use the event though with the following code and have to write a implementation for IOnClicked for the following code:

```
HorizontalPicker Picker = view.FindViewById<Com.Wefika.Horizontalpicker.HorizontalPicker>(Resource.Id.numberPicker);
HorizontalPickerItemClicked itemclicked = new HorizontalPickerItemClicked();
Picker.SetOnItemClickedListener(itemclicked);
```

Updated Implementation:

```
public class HorizontalPickerItemClicked : HorizontalPicker.IOnItemClicked
{
    public void Dispose()
    {

    }

    public IntPtr Handle { get; }
    public void OnItemClicked(int p0)
    {
        // Do something with p0
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have an Example for "Your IOnClicked Implementation"?

Comment: Updated. Another option might be to adjust the HorizontalPicker class or to re-map it in the binding library, but iam not sure how to do that there.

Comment: internal class Clicker : Java.Lang.Object, HorizontalPicker.IOnItemClicked 
    {
        private HorizontalPicker.IOnItemClicked _onItemClickedImplementation;
     
        public void OnItemClicked(int p0)
        {
            MessageBus.Default.Post("1");
        }
    }